# How to reset identity in SQL Server table column?

Tags: sql-server

[image]

How to reset identity in SQL table column without deleting table data?

Comment: If you reset the identity, you're only resetting the **counter** that hands out new values - this does **NOT** update existing row values! Also: if you reset the counter to 1 (or any other low value), you're bound to run into **duplicates** - so all in all, it's a really **horribly bad idea** to want to reset the identity values - ***WHY*** do you want to do this??

Comment: RESEED statement will not duplicate your IDENTITY column, because it only starts from where your last record inserted

Comment: @irfan_m *"it only starts from where your last record inserted"* is not correct, it starts from wherever it is seeded. i.e. It works like marc_s said.

Comment: @Anjig Can you clarify what you mean about "without deleting table data" - do you mean that you would like to "update" the table, and just assign different values for the `id` column? And can you confirm there no foreign keys referencing this `id`?

Comment: @marc_s I think it's not about resetting the seed, but about updating IDs (identity column), which can be done fairly easy by deleting rows and inserting them back with updated IDs, as I proposed in my answer.

Comment: You are not using `IDENTITY` properly if you need to do this. Auto-generated identity values are intended to be used as a surrogate key so the min, max and gaps should not be a concern.

Answer (score 1):

As Marc_s commented by resetting identity you might end up with duplicate records issue

How ever if you still want to reset the identity here is the thing that you can do

e.g. let's call `table A` in which you want to reset the identity
just create a same table with different name like `table B` same as the `table A`
now copy the `table A`'s data into `table B`
now truncate or delete the data in `table A` and reset the identity column in `table A`

this is the way you can reset the identity without losing any data or without any duplicate record issue

How ever this one way to achieve your goal 
i am not sure about whether it correct or not

Comment: This answer describes how to move the data to a different table to give it different identity values. I struggle to see how that is going to help, given that the OP has stated "without deleting table data", which implies that they need the existing data to remain where it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reset command

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('table_name', RESEED, 1)
```

**Syntax**

('table_name', RESEED, 1) where "1" is your reset point start_number. From where new Index will start.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (necessary comments in code):

```
--smple data preparation
--insert values to have 1 through 5 IDs, delete first three
create table tbl(id int identity(1,1) primary key, [name] char(1));
insert into tbl ([name]) values
('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('e');
delete from tbl where id <=3
--create helper table to hold data from our table with updated IDs
create table #helpTmpTbl(id int, [name] char(1));
--updated IDs are obtained with ROW_NUMBER function
insert into #helpTmpTbl
select row_number() over (order by id), [name] from tbl
--here you are exposed to risk of losing data, so we need to use transaction
begin tran
begin try
    --delete records from table
    delete from tbl
    --enable inserting identity column (and always remember to disable it!)
    set identity_insert tbl ON
    --insert rows with updated IDs
    insert into tbl (id, [name])
    select * from #helpTmpTbl
    --disable inserting identity column
    set identity_insert tbl OFF
    --if everything is successful, commit transaction
    commit tran
end try
begin catch
    rollback tran
end catch

select * from tbl
--get rid of the helper table
drop table #helpTmpTb
```